# Is there any alternative for setWindowAnimations(Android) in Harmony OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am developing a Harmony application and I want to animate the Dialog window 
this code is from android and this type of animation I want to add

```
Window dialogWindow = dialog.getWindow();
dialogWindow.setWindowAnimations(R.style.CustomDialogAnimation);
```

```
// properties that needs to be attached to Dialog window
duration="75"
fromXScale="0"
fromYScale="0"
toXScale="1"
toYScale="1"
```

I didn't find anything matching documentation like **setWindowAnimations**.
I tried writing this code but hit a dead end after getting the dialog window. How to add animation properties to this dialog window.

```
CommonDialog commonDialog = new CommonDialog(getContext);
Window dialogWindow = commonDialog.getWindow();
```

Is there any other way to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the team, HarmonyOS does not currently support to add animation properties to dialog window. Please stay tuned on HarmonyOS official websites.